# Use of cut command in unix

Tags: unix, cut

Suppose I have string as follwing:

Rajat;Harshit Srivastava;Mayank 123;5

Now i want result as following using cut command 
Rajat
Harshit Srivastava
Mayank 123
5
I have tried but cut is not working on string containing spaces.

Comment: srry i asked for cut command

Answer (score 1):

`man cut` would tell you:

```
   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
          use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

   --output-delimiter=STRING
          use  STRING  as  the  output delimiter the default is to use the
          input delimiter
```

If you insist on using `cut` for changing the delimiters:

```
$ echo "Rajat;Harshit Srivastava;Mayank 123;5" | cut -d \; --output-delimiter=\  -f 1-
Rajat Harshit Srivastava Mayank 123 5
```

but instead you should use `sed` or `tr` or awk for it. Try `man tr`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "Rajat;Harshit Srivastava;Mayank 123;5" | sed 's/;/ /g'
```

Comment: if i want each string in different variable??

Comment: Each string in different variable??? `for SUBSTR in $(echo "Rajat;Harshit Srivastava;Mayank 123;5" | sed 's/;/\n/g')
do
eval "$SUBSTR"="$SUBSTR"
done`